# How to save file with Capacitor on iOS?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5

I have the following code (adapted from [this tutorial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/your-first-app/3-saving-photos)) that I use for saving files from backend:

```
import { FilesystemDirectory, Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { Filesystem } = Plugins;

await Filesystem.writeFile({
    path: "filename.txt",
    data: "base64 data",
    directory: FilesystemDirectory.Documents,
  });
```

This codes works fine on Android, even creates the `Documents` directory in the root of internal storage. Unfortunately, on iOS no file is created, no mater what directory I use (I've tested it with `Documents`, `Data` and `ExternalStorage`).
When I put this code block inside `try..catch`, nothing is thrown, so the operation is supposedly completed successfully, just no file is saved. Tested on one Android device and two iOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iOS doesn't allow accessing file storage directly. I made it work with Ionic-native's [FileOpener](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener) like this:

```
import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener/ngx';
import { FilesystemDirectory, Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { Filesystem } = Plugins;

const result = await Filesystem.writeFile({
    path: "filename.txt",
    data: "base64 data",
    directory: FilesystemDirectory.Documents,
  });
this.fileOpener.showOpenWithDialog(result.uri, 'application/json')
```

It opens a dialog where you can select where to save your file. It's a bit confusing as the function's description is "Opens with system modal to open file with an already installed app" but saving works with it as well.

You need to also install cordova-plugin-file-opener2 and put ionic FileOpener to providers in app.module.ts. If you are not using Cordova otherwise, you don't need to do Cordova setups, it works alongside Capacitor as a separate plugin. As far as I'm aware, Capacitor doesn't provide a solution for downloading in iOS.

Comment: some ios apps are showing download media dialogue, how some apps can achieve it? does apple provide special apis to corporate companies?

Answer (score 7):

I've encountered the same problem (while having capacitor 4.2.0 only) and solved it by adding the following permissions in my Info.plist:

```
  <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
  <string>YES</string>

  <key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
  <string>YES</string>
```

After this, using directory `Directory.Documents` has made me visible a Documents directory with the name of the app under the Files App.

Hope it helps.

Comment: guess this should be the accepted answer worked for me and is exactly as described in the official capacitor doc https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem

Comment: However, when you delete the app, the folder and files are deleted, as well (which it does not say will happen in the Capacitor Filesystem docs). I need to save files to the Documents folder that will stay after I delete the iOS app. How do I do that? Both Documents and ExternalStorage say the files should stay, but both are being deleted when the app is deleted.

Comment: Works capacitor/filesystem 5.2.1 and capacitor core 5.0.0. Thanks @Paul